# Correlation of likert scales for different questions

Tags: correlation, likert

Can you correlate 2 Likert scales when the question for each one was different?

I have 1 question which asks how concerned someone is about pollution. They rank this on a Likert Scale of 1-5 where 1 is most concerned and 5 not at all.

Then my other question asks whether people intend to take any extra measures to reduce their own pollution in future, again on a scale of 1-5 but where 1 is very likely down to 5 not at all.

Can I run a correlation test on these two questions? Naturally I would expect the more concerned one is, the greater their intention to act. Obviously both scales are 1-5 but as the meaning behind what the number means is slightly different (I.e in Q1, 1= Most Concerned and in Q2, 1= Very Likely), can they still be correlated?

Comment: No problem, @s94, & you're welcome. If you [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) your [account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts), you'll be able to come back & ask more questions when you need help, & you'll accrue reputation from your various questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, almost all correlations are run with variables that measure different (but hopefully related) things.  You may prefer to use Spearman's correlation for Likert items.